# how can I get file name when I use jquery uploadFile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-upload-file-plugin

I want to get file name after user uploading file in same page.

How could I do ?

Please give me some advices.

Here is my simple code.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/ecmascript" src="../_js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="../_js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Upload File -->
<link href="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/uploadfile.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var extraObj = $("#drop").uploadFile({
        url:"fileupload.php",
        fileName:"myfile",
        autoSubmit:false
    });

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        //alert(I want get file name here);
        extraObj.startUpload();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="drop" type="file">Upload File</div>
    <form role="form" method="post" action="">
        <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127350/how-to-get-filename-on-html-javascript-jquery-drag-drop-event-non-html5)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
I find other method to get file name.
I use onSuccess:function
http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#single

Answer (score 0):

console.log(data.originalFiles[0].name)
Please use this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you give an answer, please, try to give some explanation as the user is trying to know what to do, not just one line of code.